# report server: add to line plot one more line with summa

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, power-bi-report-server

Would you prompt me, please how to create the additional line on the line chart, which contains sum over all the lines in the chart.

E.g.:
-we have sales over months:
-x-axis is months
-y-axis is sum of sales

On the line chart, we have 3 lines:
-sales on office1
-sales on office2
-sales on office3

On the same chart, I need to add a line with summa of sales over 3 offices.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what your dataset looks like but the easiest way is usually to do this in your dataset query and supply the 'Total' office numbers in the same manner as the current numbers.

So, if your data looked like this

| Office | Month | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Office1 | 01 | 1000 |
| Office2 | 01 | 1100 |
| Office3 | 01 | 1200 |
| Office1 | 02 | 1300 |
| Office2 | 02 | 1400 |
| Office3 | 02 | 1600 |
| Office1 | 03 | 1700 |
| Office2 | 03 | 1800 |

Then you could do something simple like

```
SELECT Office, Month , Amount FROM myTable
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Total', Month, SUM(Amount) from myTable GROUP BY Month
```

This way "Total" just gets displayed like any other office.